# Upgrading Artifactory from 2.6.2 to 4.7.4

Tags: artifactory

my company is using artifactory 2.6.2 version. They want to upgrade it to the latest version (4.7.4). Any idea how to proceed ...?Or is there any link or documentation to follow?

Answer (score 2):

You need to first upgrade 2.x -> 3.x using this [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF3X/Upgrading+Artifactory), once you did that you can upgrade 3.x -> 4.x using this [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Upgrading+Artifactory).